# UIDatePicker shows 12-h time instead of 24-h time

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, locale, uidatepicker

I've found some very strange behaviour in `UIDatePicker`: in my iPhone's settings I've select 24-h time but `UIDatePicker`still shows 12-h time.

The local of `UIDatePicker` is `default` (based on user settings).

**How to reproduce:**

Preconditions:

- iPhone language should be English
- 24 hours format should be set
- Timezone should be set as automatic
- iPhone region: Ukraine

Steps:

1. Change iPhone language to Ukrainian(haven't tested with other
   languages)
2. Change timezone to Manual
3. Switch 24-h time format to 12-h
4. Switch 12-h time format to 24-h

As a result, we get the following: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYZDr.jpg)

**Question:** Is it the iOS bug or just my mistake?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Compare  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1151335/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230569/1187415

Answer (score 0):

You can set the locale to auto update based on the user preferences like this

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't help